# Get variable value from hashmap in Struts2

Tags: struts2, hashmap

i have a Struts2 action, in which i declare a hashmap and populate values in it. i want to access the value in the hashmap in the jsp page. the key to the corresponding value is obtained as a variable in the jsp. i have tried the following:

```
<tr class="gradeA">
    <td><s:property value="companyName" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="fname" /> <s:property value="lname" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="primaryPhone" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="email1" /></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{map[deliveryType]}" /></td>
    <td><a href="<s:property value="#editUrl" />">Edit </a>
</tr>
```

map is the name of the hashmap instance which i created in the action and deliveryType is the variable which contains the key. any way i can obtain the value corresponding to the key?

Comment: Is it a local variable or it's accessable for expression evaluation?

Answer (score 4):

```
<s:property value="map['%{deliveryType}']" />
```

Obviously both map and deliveryType must have a Getter.